# Having a curved arrow instead

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{r}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{g\circ f} & B \arrow{d}{g} \\
     & C
  \end{tikzcd}
```

but I need to have a curved arrow from A to C, any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You only need to add option `bend left` or `bend right` option to arrow which you like to make "curved". BTW, here is very desired, that you provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, which reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any reason that you like to have bended the arrow. Original straight is just fine. Anyway, you only need to add option `bend right` (or `bend left`) to arrow, which you like to bend.

MWE below gives result of your original code (left image) and with bended arrow (right image). For the right image are used `tikz-cd` syntax described in section *1.4 Alternative syntax for arrows* on page 4:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}
 A \arrow{r}{f} \arrow[swap]{dr}{g\circ f} 
        & B \arrow{d}{g} \\
        & C
    \end{tikzcd}

    \begin{tikzcd}
A \rar{f} \drar[bend right, "g\circ f" ']
        & B \dar{g} \\
        & C
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there a code with documentclass{article}?

Comment: @mathmusic, code for diagram is the same for any document class. You only need to replace `[border=3.141592]{standalone}` with  `{article}`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In the tikzcd documentation, they have the following examples, I hope this helps:

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  T
  \arrow[drr, bend left, "x"]
  \arrow[ddr, bend right, "y"]
  \arrow[dr, dotted, "{(x,y)}" description] & & \\
    & X \times_Z Y \arrow[r, "p"] \arrow[d, "q"]
      & X \arrow[d, "f"] \\
& Y \arrow[r, "g"] &Z
\end{tikzcd}
```

[image]

Comment: No it is a complicated example, I just need a solution in my case please.

Comment: True, it's quite complicated to read by a human.